# Linq Join Multiple Criteria (Number not known beforehand)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I need to join multiple criteria inside a linq query, I have a criteria box like below :

[image]

Currently Im using a query than can only handle a single tag :

```
var c = *text after the t:*
var r = rs.Returns.Where(x => x.Lines.Any(y => y.Tags.Any(z => z.Name.Contains(c))));
```

I need something like (this may be incorrect) :

```
var r = rs.Returns.Where(x => x.Lines.Any(y => y.Tags.Any(z => z.Name.Contains(*1st Tag*)) && y.Tags.Any(z.Name.Contains(*2nd Tag*)))); .. etc
```

So that all the `tags` the `Line` has are searched and `AND` is applied. Is there an easy way of achieving such a thing?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
var r = rs.Returns.Where(x => x.Lines.Any(y => searchTags.All(stag => y.Tags.Any(z => z.Name.Contains(stag)))));
```

searchTags should contain all tags to search for. No need to use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
List<string> tags = new List<string>() { "tag1", "tag2" };

var query = rs.Returns.AsEnumerable();
foreach(string tag in tags)
{
  string tmp = tag;
  query = query.Where(x => x.Lines.Any(y => y.Tags.Any(z => z.Name.Contains(tmp))));
}
```